# How to update Samsung Galaxy SII SHW-250K from ICS to jelly bean?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, samsung-galaxy-s-2, updates, 4.1-jelly-bean, 4.2-jelly-bean

How can I update Samsung Galaxy SII SHW-250K from ICS (4.0.4) to jelly bean?
I tried using samsung kies but it shows that 
"SHW-250K does not support initialising".

Answer (score 1):

You can simply flash win Odin GT-I9100 firmware.
Firmwares you can get from sammobile

Odin you can get from http://web.djodjo.org/?a=download:android:tools:win:bootloadertools

get Odin307

You can also check this [tutorial](http://blog.djodjo.org/?p=425) for flashing with Odin.